# Mootools - Scope problem in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, mootools

Im starting to play with mootools but not sure why the following will hide me options in a select list, but in IE it will not:

```
<select id="test_select" multiple>
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
        <option>C</option>
</select>

$$('#test_select option').each(function(el){
        el.addClass('hide');
});
```

I really would appreciate a bit of help on this...

Comment: which version of mootools are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide an option in a select you must remove the Option from the select in IE.

Here is an explanation in further detail [Hide Option in Select](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/567819-how-hide-options-select)

To remove option element from Select w/ Mootools you can do the following:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c63ZP/1/)

```
$$('#test_select option').each(function(el){
        if(el.get("html") == 'A')
            el.destroy();
});
```

Comment: sup kj, hows tricks! +1 - ought to `.get("html")` instead to be moocools compliant! :)

Comment: oh noze its Dimitar =P the mootools stackoverflow rep stealer ;O!

Comment: you are unlikely to get rep for this answer by 'user589124' of rep 1, first question and all that... prolly not going to bother to upvote or accept... At least you get the rep I left you :)

Comment: @Dimitar ya, i figured lol.  Thanks =P Lesson learned that's for sure.